# How to handle hidden div id dynamically with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, hidden

I'm trying to do a dynamic page, I have a hidden div and I want make it visible appending to another div, but I want to do it with only one function here is my code.

```
<script>
var hiddenDivID;
function appendHiddenDiv(hiddenDivID){
    var hiddenDiv = document.getElementById(hiddenDivID);
    var document = document.getElementById('content');
    document.appendChild(hiddenDiv);
}

function choices(e){
   if(e.id == 03){
    appendHiddenDiv('myHiddenDiv');
   }
}
```

```
<!-- Visible Content-->
<div id="content">
 My content
</div>
<span id="03" onclick="choices(this);">Click Here</span>
<!-- Visible Content-->

<!-- Invisible Content-->
  <div id="contentHidden">
    <div id ="myHiddenDiv">
       Hidden content
    </div>
  </div>
<!-- Invisible Content-->
```

I've made a function that says if I hit Click Here `hiddenDivID = myHiddenDiv` and calls the `appendHiddenDiv()` so it takes `myHiddenDiv` and appends to `<div id="content"></div>`. But it doesn't work, what I'm doing wrong in this? there is a way to make the function recognize that as an id? If there is, can someone please put me on the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will append your div when you click on it.  You had e.id == 03, and you needed e.id == '03' (id is a string).

```
<script>
var hiddenDivID;
function appendHiddenDiv(hiddenDivID){
    var hiddenDiv = window.document.getElementById(hiddenDivID);
    var document = window.document.getElementById('content');
    document.appendChild(hiddenDiv);
}

function choices(e){

   if(e.id == '03'){
    appendHiddenDiv('myHiddenDiv');
   }
}
</script>



<div id="content">
 My content
</div>
<span id="03" onclick="choices(this);">Click Here</span>
<!-- Visible Content-->

<!-- Invisible Content-->
  <div id="contentHidden">
    <div id ="myHiddenDiv">
       Hidden content
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: It works fine, it was so simple, how could I miss that! Anyway, thanks man, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things here and I have a suggestion to both. I think that if you are just hiding an element and then making it appear on click then there is no need to have the two separated in your HTML just to append them latter. You can just hide and show them. (display: none and display:block). the function is also more flexible. You can use it on any element with an id you like.

#### HTML

```
<!-- Visible Content-->
<div id="content">
 My content
</div>
<span id="03" onclick="choices(this)">Click Here

<!-- Invisible Content-->
  <div id="contentHidden">
    <div id ="myHiddenDiv">
       Hidden content
    </div>
  </div>
<!-- Invisible Content-->

</span>
<!-- Visible Content-->
```

#### CSS

```
#contentHidden{
display:none;
}
```

#### JS

```
<script>
function choices(e){
    var elemId = e.id, // get the id of the clicked element
        hiddenElem = e.children[0]; // get the child of the clicked element

    // if the hidden elements display style is set to none or undefined, set it to block 
    if (hiddenElem.style.display === "none" || hiddenElem.style.display === "" ){
        hiddenElem.style.display = "block";
    } 
}
</script>
```

### Better Approach

I like this method better. You have your base HTML and then add your "hidden" element dynamiclly. This way you can add this function to the element you want and the text.

#### HTML

```
<!-- Visible Content-->
<div id="content">
 My content
</div>
<span id="03" onclick="choices(this)">Click Here

</span>
<!-- Visible Content-->
```

#### JS

```
function choices(e, txt){
       var elemId = e.id, // get the id of the clicked element
           hiddenElem = e.children[0]; // get the child of the clicked element
           makeElem = document.createElement("div"); // create a div element

       makeElem.textContent = txt; // set the text of the div element to that passed by the function arrument 
       e.appendChild(makeElem); // append the created element to the clicked element
    }
```